# Does there exist a matrix $P$ such that $P^n=M$ for a special matrix $M$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the matrix
$$
M=\left(\begin{matrix}
0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
\end{matrix}\right).
$$
Is there a matrix $P\in{\Bbb C}^{4\times 4}$ such that $P^n=M$ for some $n>1$?

---

One obvious fact is that if such $P$ exists, then $P$ must be nilpotent. However, I have no idea how to deal with this problem. Furthermore, what if $M$ is an arbitrary nilpotent matrix with index $k$?

Comment: Cube a nilpotent $4 \times 4$ [Jordan block](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_block)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Purely by trial and error, let
$$P=\left(\begin{matrix}
0&1&1&1\\
0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
\end{matrix}\right)$$ which squares to $M$.

The matrix
$$P=\left(\begin{matrix}
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
\end{matrix}\right)$$
and its anti-transpose are more simple and also work.

Comment: This has two unnecessary positive entries.

Comment: Yes, there appear to many solutions. Some more simple.

Comment: To be more specific to vadim123's comment, a matrix of this form will work for any $a$ and $b$: $$P=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&a&b\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$ where $a=b=0$ gives the nicest result.

Answer (score 2):

For 
$P=\left(\begin{matrix}
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&0\\
\end{matrix}\right)$

$P^3=M$.

Can we find a matrix $P$ such that $P^n=M$ for some $n>3$? Or for which $n$ does there exist $P$ s.t $P^n=M$?

Answer (score 0):

Since it has been proposed to treat [this Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/625218/for-which-n-in-bbb-z-does-there-exist-a-matrix-p-in-bbb-c4-times-4) as a duplicate of the present one, it should be noted that there is a negative Answer to the "new" issue raised [in Yeyeye's Answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/411093/3111).

As earlier observed, since $M$ is nilpotent, for $P^n = M$ for $n\gt 1$ will require that $P$ is nilpotent.  It follows that the minimal polynomial for $P$ must divide $x^d$ where $d$ is the degree of nilpotency (i.e. the least power such that $P^d=0$.

Now the characteristic polynomial of $P$ will have degree $4$ (because $P$ is $4\times 4$), and thus $d\le 4$.  So the minimal polynomial of $P$ has the form $x^k$ for $1\lt k \le d \le 4$.  In other words, $P^4=0$ given the above information.  So $P^3 = M \neq 0$ is the largest power $n=3$ that one can achieve.