# Square Matrix example

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How can i find a 2x2 and 4 x 4 square matrix whose fourth power is zero but so that none of its lower power is zero.

I could find 2x2 matrix with this condition but someone can help me with the 4 x4 matrix please...

Comment: So the minimal polynomial of the matrix is $x^4$. But the minimal polynomial is a divisor of the characteristic polynomial, and the characteristic polynomial of a 2x2 matrix has degree 2. Your claim seems to be impossible.

Comment: Why don't you try making your 4x4 matrix by putting two copies of your 2x2 matrix on the diagonal and all zeros on the off diagonal.

Comment: possible duplicate of [For which ${n\in{\Bbb Z}}$ does there exist a matrix $P\in{\Bbb C}^{4\times 4}$ such that $P^n=M$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/625218/for-which-n-in-bbb-z-does-there-exist-a-matrix-p-in-bbb-c4-times-4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my answer [earlier today](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/625218/for-which-n-in-bbb-z-does-there-exist-a-matrix-p-in-bbb-c4-times-4/625243#625243).

Assuming you are working over $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ or $\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ you always have $A^n=0$ for nilpotent matrices $A$.

Answer (score 2):

Although the 2x2 case is not possible the 4x4 case is, which I think is the point of the exercise. Look into the Cayley - Hamilton theorem, minimal polynomials, and nilpotent matrices. In the mean time consider...
 \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}

Comment: Also:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & a & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & a & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & a\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

with $a\in\Bbb R$.